# How do I say that something will "probably" happen in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

I was recently writing in Latin and had the misfortune of getting an English construction in my head that I had a difficult time fitting into a Latin thought pattern:

> I will probably be there soon.

I ended up settling on something pretty different:

> Credo me mox adfuturum.

Though this works, for the most part, it does not quite preserve the full sense of the English phrase. Here are some other example sentences I am interested in translating:

> Are you coming with me? --**Probably**.
>   It is **probable** that he won't come.

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot think of an adverb/adjective that can be idiomatically used in these cases. The adjective [*probabilis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dprobabilis) is one possibility, but it has a wide scope, and it appears that *one* of its usages has been narrowed to the current English meaning. I tend to think that "probabile est" is far less common--and far less specific--than English "it is probable."

**What is the best Latin word or idiom to express that something is "likely" or "probable"?**

Comment: Good question! I don't know a suitable adverb or adjective either, but I would use *credo* or *fieri potest* in some way. There's also the potential conjunctive, but it doesn't get the tone right either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Smith's English-Latin lists a few alternatives, all sourced, under *probably*, which suffice in most circumstances. In summary,

1. With probability but not certainty : *probabiliter* ; *cum quadam verisimilitudine*.
2. By circumlocution : *veri simile est*; *haud scio an*.

Not put forward by Smith are such approaches as *nescio quin . . . '*, which I take to imply something like '[in my opinion] very likely' : perhaps indicating a less definite probability.

Comment: These are great options, though I still think they don't quite capture "probably." *Visne mecum ire? --Probabiliter* doesn't sound quite write to me, almost like, "It could be demonstrated!"

Comment: If you are asking for an improved translation we should need a bit of background before choosing an appropriate Latin idiom. You may find it more polite to use _comitari_ for _mecum ire_, and _velis_ rather than _vis_; to reply 'probably' in your example I'd use _veri simile [est]_; and so on, trying to temper the style of your translation to the circumstances. Would that make it any easier?

Comment: Two of these options are also given by Cassell, viz. *probabiliter* and *veri simile est*.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is the adverb *fortasse* (and *fortassis*).

According to Lewis & Short on the Latin word *fortasse*,<sup>1</sup>

> fortassē (also fortassis , but rarely, and not in Caes.; Plaut. As. 2, 4, 86; id. Bacch. 4, 4, 20; Cic. Clu. 52, 144 Klotz, B. and K.; 71, 201 B. and K.; Hor. S. 1, 4, 131; 2, 7, 40; Plin. 2, 20, 18, § 82; 27, 12, 77, § 102; Traj. ap. Plin. Ep. 10, 63; Dig. 7, 1, 12, § 5; 11, 7, 14, § 9), adv. forte an; cf.: forsan, fortan,
>
> I.perhaps, peradventure, **probably**, possibly: “nescis tu fortasse, apud nos facinus quod natum est novum,” Plaut. Mil. 2, 3, 10: “dicam me hercule, et contemnar a te fortasse, cum tu, etc.,” Cic. Rep. 1, 19; 2, 34: “in quo (genere) esse videbuntur fortasse angustiae,” id. ib. 3, 33: “fortasse dices: Quid ergo?” id. Div. in Caecil. 12, 40: “requiretur fortasse nunc, quemadmodum, etc.,” id. de Imp. Pomp. 9, 22: “quaeret fortassis quispiam, displiceatur mihi, etc.,” id. Clu. 52, 144: “fortasse dixerit quispiam,” id. de Sen. 3, 8 (for which: “forsitan quispiam dixerit,” id. Off. 3, 6, 29): “sed haec longiora fortasse fuerunt quam necesse, fuit,” id. Fam. 6, 1, 7; cf. id. ib. 7, 3 fin.: “sustines enim non parvam exspectationem imitandae industriae nostrae, magnam honorum, nonnullam fortasse nominis,” id. Off. 3, 2, 6: “poterimus fortasse dicere,” id. Or. 5, 19: “quod tamen fortasse non nollem,” id. Fam. 2, 16, 2; cf.: “L. Lucullus, qui tamen aliqua ex parte iis incommodis mederi fortasse potuisset, etc.,” id. de Imp. Pomp. 9, 26: “puerum, inquies, et fortasse fatuum,” id. Att. 6, 6, 2; cf.: “otioso et loquaci et fortasse docto atque erudito,” id. de Or. 1, 22, 102.—With sed: “praeclaram illam quidem fortasse, sed a vita hominum abhorrentem,” Cic. Rep. 2, 11; cf.: “Marso fortasse, sed Romano facillimus,” id. Div. 2, 33, 70; 2, 22, 50; id. Tusc. 1, 13, 30.—With nisi (for nisi forte): “tu hoc: alius fortasse, quod in animadversione poenaque durior, nisi fortasse utrumque tu,” id. ad Brut. 1, 15, 3.—With sed tamen, Plaut. As. 2, 4, 86; Cic. Rep. 2, 33; id. Off. 3, 21, 82; id. Sest. 5, 12.—With verum tamen, Cic. Verr. 1, 12, 35; id. Arch. 11, 28. —With quidem: “id nos fortasse non perfecimus, conati quidem saepissime sumus,” Cic. Or. 62, 210; so id. Tusc. 2, 17, 41: “res enim fortasse verae, certe graves,” id. Fin. 4, 3, 7.—
>
> b. In Plaut. and Ter. ellipt., like fors, with a subject-clause: “fortasse te illum mirari cocum, Quod venit atque haec attulit,” it may be that, perhaps, Plaut. Merc. 4, 4, 42; id. As. 1, 1, 24; id. Ep. 2, 2, 111; id. Poen. 5, 2, 44; id. Truc. 3, 2, 12; Ter. Hec. 3, 1, 33; cf.: sic Plautus: Fortasse ted amare suspicarier. Nam veteres infinitivo modo adjungebant fortasse, Don. Ter. 1, 1; cf. ellipt. use: Q. unum illud mihi videris imitari, orationis genus. M. Velle fortasse; “quis enim id potest imitari?” Cic. Leg. 2, 7, 17.—
>
> c. Ironically (cf. forte, 2, a. β and Gr. ἴσως): Ch. Prorsum nihil intellego. Sy. Hui, tardus es. Ch. Fortasse, Ter. Heaut. 4, 5, 29: “sed ego fortasse vaticinor, et haec omnia meliores habebunt exitus ... eos ego fortasse nunc imitor,” Cic. Fam. 2, 16, 6; Plaut. As. 2, 4, 90.—
>
> d. In designating numbers, about (in Cic. usually placed after the numeral): “elegit ex multis Isocratis libris triginta fortasse versus Hieronymus,” Cic. Or. 56, 190: “Q. Pompeius biennio quam nos fortasse major,” id. Brut. 68, 240: “HS. D. milia fortasse,” Cic. Verr. 2, 3, 50, § 118: “fuimus una horas duas fortasse,” id. Att. 7, 4, 2: “fortasse circiter triennium,” Plaut. Mil. 2, 3, 79: “mercaris agrum, fortasse trecentis, aut etiam supra, nummorum milibus emptum,” Hor. Ep. 2, 2, 164.

---

### References

Lewis, Charlton T.; Short, Charles. [*Harper’s Latin Dictionary: A New Latin Dictionary Founded on the Translation of Freund’s Latin-German Lexicon.*](https://archive.org/details/harperslatindict00lewi) New York: American Book, 1879.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> p. [771–772](https://archive.org/stream/harperslatindict00lewi#page/771/mode/1up)

Comment: I have always read "fortasse" as "maybe, maybe not." Do you think it refers to something more likely?

Comment: @brianpck—Honestly, I do not know. :|

Comment: I am no expert, but the Oxford Latin Dictionary has "fortasse" as "it may be, perhaps, possibly (sts. iron.)".  (Is "probably" an ironical use of "fortasse"?) Even the L&S definition is hardly encouraging: I suspect people want to use a word for "probably" that will actually be interpreted as meaning "probably", rather than one as vague as to be translated "perhaps, peradventure, probably, possibly".  Though Döderlein and Ramshorn give *some* support to "probably" (see Joef Derfner's answer), descriptions like "approaching to probability" possibly fall short of the usual meaning of "probably".

Answer (score 6):

Dōderlein, p. 33, has

> *Fortasse, forsitan,*...denote possibility, and indeed, *fortasse, fortassis* with an emphatic perception and affirmation of the possibility as approaching to probability...*forsitan, forsan* with merely an occasional perception of the possibility.

Ramshorn, meanwhile, p. 217, has

> *Forsan*...and *forsitan*...are used if something is imagined as possible....*Fortasse*...if the supposition is pronounced with a belief in the probability of the event.

To be honest, I'm not quite sure how much I trust them here. Just in case, though, my *forsitan* usually stays in the middle between e.g. *nonne* and *num*, whereas my *fortasse* is a little closer to *nonne*.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit of a stretch, but have you considered using the *potentialis* ? Then it just becomes:

> Mox adsim.

I'm expecting some reservations from you on this one, because I'm not 100% convinced either. It seems to me that the focus is put on *being there*, not on being there *soon*.

I think the construction is better suited to the last example sentence:

> Non veniat.